# EBS Backed Windows Instance AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows

Easy points here (cash in on my laziness!), but I'm not seeing an EBS backed Windows 2003 instance from the Amazon public AMIs repo.  Do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only Windows instances that AWS offers above the fold are 2008 ones. 2003R2 is there if you hunt for them, including SQL varieties.

[image: AWS AMI browser showing Windows]

Don't use the quick-launcher to find them.

Comment: Ok, just saw this (http://aws.amazon.com/amis/AWS/3180), but not sure if it's EBS backed or not.  Need 32-bit as I want a small instance.

Comment: doh, says it right in the description (lazy _and_ unobservant today!)

Answer (score 2):

Amazon does offer Windows Server 2003 R2 in EBS - it is just not 'on display'. Look under the community AMIs, and filter by Amazon Images. The following come up when I search (all are EBS backed and 'official' Amazon images):

```
ami-0391476a - amazon/Windows-2003R2-i386-Base-2012.01.12
ami-0791476e - amazon/Windows-2003R2-SqlExpress-2012.01.12
ami-0b8b5d62 - amazon/Windows-2003R2-SqlStandard-2012.01.12
ami-1f914776 - amazon/Windows-2003R2-Base-2012.01.12
ami-31914758 - amazon/Windows-2003R2-i386-SqlExpress-2012.01.12
ami-35f5235c - amazon/Windows-2003R2-i386-BaseMultiLang-2012.01.12
ami-49f12720 - amazon/Windows-2003R2-SQLStandardMultiLang-2012.01.12
ami-4bf52322 - amazon/Windows-2003R2-SQLExpressMultiLang-2012.01.12
ami-c5f721ac - amazon/Windows-2003R2-i386-SQLExpressMultiLang-2012.01.12
ami-e5f5238c - amazon/Windows-2003R2-BaseMultiLang-2012.01.12
```

Slightly more elegantly, you can use `ec2-describe-instances` to get the same result (I am using i386, because of your comment, above):

```
ec2-describe-images --filter "is-public=true" --filter "architecture=i386" --filter "platform=windows" --filter "image-type=machine" --filter "root-device-type=ebs"  --owner "amazon"

IMAGE   ami-0391476a    amazon/Windows-2003R2-i386-Base-2012.01.12                      amazon  available       public      i386    machine      windows     ebs     hvm     xen      BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1       snap-02fc9c66   20
IMAGE   ami-35f5235c    amazon/Windows-2003R2-i386-BaseMultiLang-2012.01.12             amazon  available       public      i386    machine      windows     ebs     hvm     xen      BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1       snap-80463ee4   20
IMAGE   ami-31914758    amazon/Windows-2003R2-i386-SqlExpress-2012.01.12                amazon  available       public      i386    machine      windows     ebs     hvm     xen      BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1       snap-9ee787fa   20
IMAGE   ami-c5f721ac    amazon/Windows-2003R2-i386-SQLExpressMultiLang-2012.01.12       amazon  available       public      i386    machine      windows     ebs     hvm     xen      BLOCKDEVICEMAPPING      /dev/sda1       snap-4c7a0228   20
```

(The above returns both Windows 2003 and 2008 - so either grep, or select by hand - obviously the difference between the two result sets is because the latter is limited to i386 only. The above command does appear to need a key and certificate to run).